# Como exibir posts de um wordpress em uma página inicial

Tags: wordpress, cms

Bem, queria saber qual função eu utilizo para exibir todos os artigos de meu blog em um tema que eu estou criando, já revirei a internet e não achei nada. seria com um get_posts?

Comment: o que você já tentou?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o código abaixo:

```
get_header();
    if (have_posts()): 
        foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
              the_title();
        endforeach; // foreach($posts
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
    endif;
get_footer();
```